# How to format Powershell CanonicalName into separate column?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to separate the result below so the one-column called CanonicalName can be separated into: `CanonicalName, ComputerName, DateEncrypted`

Code:

```
$includeOUs = @(
   'Laptops'
    'Laptop'
   'Remote Offices'
) | ForEach-Object {
   If ($ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "name -eq '$($_)'" -Properties canonicalName) {
      $ou
   }
   Else {
      Throw "OU '$($_)' not found!"
   }
}

$includeOUs | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName | 
Foreach-Object{
        Get-ADObject -ldapfilter "(msFVE-Recoverypassword=*)" -Searchbase $_ -Properties canonicalname,msfve-recoverypassword,msTPM-OwnerInformation | 
Select-Object canonicalname,msfve-recoverypassword,msTPM-OwnerInformation
    } | 
Out-GridView
```

Note: the name of the OU is the same throughout the different geographical locations.

```
domain.com/Site1/Laptops
domain.com/Site2/Laptops
domain.com/Site3/Laptops
```

And is there any reason why the Attributes **msTPM-OwnerInformation** is always empty?

Result:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the screenshot you've posted was produced by the code you've shown? `ogv` (`Out-GridView`) retains the order of the properties. Please post the actual code that produced the depicted gridview window

Comment: Hi @mathias, yes, I just drag the 'msTPM-OwnerInformation' column to the first column.

Comment: The attribute `msTPM-OwnerInformation` isn't getting returned at all from `Get-ADObject` Incidentally I tried `Get-ADComputer` as well and no luck.  I don't think it's always populated, so that would appropriately return null and be blank in the output.

Comment: @steven, ok so in this case, no need to worry about that 'msTPM-OwnerInformation' attribute. 
is it possible to split the column canonicalName above?

Comment: Enclose the attribute in quotes like `'msTPM-OwnerInformation'`

Comment: @Theo is correct, else the dash get's parsed incorrectly.  However, in my tests the attribute was still empty.  More to follow in answer-form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research suggests the 'msTPM-OwnerInformation' & 'msTPM-TpmInformationForComputer' attributes only populates under certain circumstances, like when forced through GPO.  And, BitLocker can indeed be enabled without them.  To clarify the TPM owner password is not the same as a BitLocker recovery key or password.

[BitLocker FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-and-adds-faq)

Also: [TPM Fundementals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/tpm-fundamentals)

Between research, practical testing and direct observation, I'm forced to conclude the column is empty because the data probably isn't there.

> Note: Withstanding @Theos correct observation

For you last comment on how to split the CanonicalName. This is a little difficult to answer for a couple of reasons. First, it's unclear what you're looking for, we have no example output to go by. Second, I might want to approach the whole problem differently.  For Example, possibly using the AD provider that's better at getting child objects. Or, I might try to build a relationship between the computer objects and their contained recovery passwords so I can craft the report properly. Those are just suggestions for brainstorming.

The current code is returning "msFVE-RecoveryInformation" objects, so the canonical name you're seeing is accurate. This is because it's a child object of the computer.  And, it's a consequence of your filter. Only objectClass msFVE-RecoveryInformation will match `"(msFVE-Recoverypassword=*)"`. A very crude way to break up the canonicalName might be something like:

```
$includeOUs | 
ForEach-Object { Get-ADObject -ldapfilter "(msFVE-Recoverypassword=*)" -Searchbase $_ -Properties $ObjProps } | 
Select-Object ObjectClass,
    @{ Name = 'ComputerPath'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalName.SubString(0, ($_.CanonicalName.LastindexOf('/') -1 ) ) } },
    @{ Name = 'RecoveryPasswordName'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalName.Split('/')[-1] } },
    msfve-recoverypassword
```

> Note: With some other changes
>
> Note: There may be more than 1 recovery password per computer.  It
> depends on how many voumes on that machine are encrypted and/or are
> stored in AD.  An Exchange server for example could have dozens of
> recovery passwords stored in AD...  An array may not format well in
> the tabular output we're discussing here.

Comment: wow, that's great explanations, yes, that does make sense and it is working great as per your parsing techniques. Many thanks for the assistance in this matter.